# How to Install VORA on a dual NameNode Cluster

Tags: vora

We have a dual NameNode Cluster, nn1 nn2, that is in failover mode. So if nn1 is down nn2 takesover. This seems to be a problem with VORA, it wants a single Namenode to deal with, HOST:PORT, when it is installed on our cluster it uses the Failover cluster name instead.

Is there a way for VORA to work with a system such as this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current Vora version 1.2 needs a manual workaround to run in such an environment (see [Issue 26 on the Vora Troubleshooting Blog](http://scn.sap.com/blogs/vora/2015/12/09/sap-hana-vora--troubleshooting#26)). Please be aware that this manual workaround does not include support for a NameNode failover. It is planned to fully support a NameNode HA environment with the next Vora version.